# Div on image should be transparent

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this:

[image]

On image (with flower) I have this CSS code:

```
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

And I want place in square div transparent so without rgba opacity (To be part of a flower in a div without darkening).
How can I do it?
Thanks for every answer.

Comment: you want the border to be transparent?

Comment: No border, but I want filling in div transparent (with opacity 1)

Comment: To be part of a flower in a div without darkening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create overlay with `:after` pseudo element and use `box-shadow`.

```css
div {
  background: url('http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 500px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can also use `svg`

```css
div {
  background: url('http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.overlay {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 400 250">
    <path class="overlay" d="M347.065,200.282H247.71V93.428h99.355V200.282z M400,0H0v250h400V0z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
div {
    background-color:transparent;
border:4px solid black
}
```

Comment: Why should he try that? Be more specific about your answer :)